# Why react firebase hook do not working to show error in sign in with email and password?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

here my code :

```
import { useSignInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';

  let [
        signInWithEmailAndPassword1,
        user,
        error,
    ] = useSignInWithEmailAndPassword(auth);
```

I tried several times to display error.message but do not showing anything and in console error is showing false when I made any error like mismatch email or passsword.

but in using sign up with email and password their hook is all ok.

Answer (score 0):

let [
createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
user,
loading,
error,
] = useSignInWithEmailAndPassword(auth);

use this.
If you do not use any of them inside the third bracket and break the sequence, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's known as [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), because the hook `useSignInWithEmailAndPassword` is returning an `Array`, JavaScript must respect the order of the object it returns.

If the return object were [a Json] `Object`, you could simply not assign the values in any order (example):

```js
const {
  key3,
  key1,
} = {
  key1: 123,
  key2: "foo",
  key3: "bar"
}
```

You may assign the variable you don't want to use as an underscore (`_`):

```js
import { useSignInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';

const [
      signInWithEmailAndPassword1,
      user,
      _,
      error,
  ] = useSignInWithEmailAndPassword(auth);
```

Alternatively, it is also valid to simply continue with the destructuring:

```js
import { useSignInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';

const [
      signInWithEmailAndPassword1,
      user,
      ,
      error,
  ] = useSignInWithEmailAndPassword(auth);
```

As a side note, unless you plan to directly change (mutate - [See Mutability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Mutable)) the value of the variables (`signInWithEmailAndPassword1`, `user`, `error`), you should use the `const` keyword when declaring them.

See [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) for some more on `const`, `let`, and (the older) `var` keywords